# latex two column layout set figure to load on single column

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, multicol

this is the double column  code

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
  \centering    
  \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
  \caption{AA \cite{BB}}
\end{figure*}

\end{multicols}
```

But the image consumes both columns. How can i make it display only on a single column ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the environment `center` instead of figure. Of course you have to use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}` or with the package caption `\captionsetup{type=figure}`.

`multicols` uses `saveboxes` to split the contents. In this case you can't use any floating material.

Example with `center`, `captionof` and `captionsetup`:
FYI: `captionof` requires the package caption or capt-of or a documentclass of the KOMA Bundle; `captionsetup` requires the package caption.

```
\documentclass[english,demo]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{AA \cite{BB}}
\end{center}
\blindtext[2]
\end{multicols}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
  \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
  \caption{AA \cite{BB}}
\end{center}
\blindtext[2]
\end{multicols}
\blindtext
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{BB} Name, Title
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The small package that only provides the `\captionof` macro is called [capt-of](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of).

Answer (score 4):

the `figure` environment don't work inside the `multicol` environment. You have to choose the `\twocolumn` command or alternatively the package `caption` and then

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{AA \cite{BB}}
\end{center}

\end{multicols}
```

However, if you want the image span both columns, then you have to split the `multicol` environment:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
foo
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering    
  \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
  \caption{AA \cite{BB}}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
bar
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very crude, how can one possibly know exactly where to begin and stop the multicol environment, in order to place a spanning image at the bottom of the page. Trial and error?... then you need to add or remove a paragraph on the previous page (for whatever reason) and everything is out of whack again. There has to be a better way.

Comment: @Herbert  multicols *does* support `figure*` and interprets them as pagewide figures, so that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use  usepackage{here} and use H

```
    \begin{multicols}{2}

   \begin{figure*}[H]
      \centering    
      \includegraphics[height=60mm]{CC.jpg}
      \caption{AA \cite{BB}}
    \end{figure*}

    \end{multicols}
```